# Proper terms for symbols

Tags: bash, shell-script

What are the proper names of following symbols/operators in Linux?

```
>
>>
<
```

Comment: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

Comment: [gnu bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) "redirection operators".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are all *redirection operators*.  The POSIX standard does not actually give these individual proper names, but defines them [in sections with the following section titles](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07):

- `<` "Redirecting input"
- `>` "Redirecting output"
- `>>` "Appending redirected output"

That is, it does not name them but lets us know what they are used for, a possible hint that they should be seen as actions/verbs.

If you called `<` "the input redirection operator", `>` "the output redirection operator", and `>>` "the appending redirection operator", people would know what you're talking about.

Likewise, if you described the operation in terms of "redirecting input from ...", "redirecting output to ...", "appending output to ...", it would also be fairly clear what you are referring to, possibly with the context of some code that you may be talking about.